# Why can't we use a superconducting $LC$ circuit as a qubit?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electric-circuits, hilbert-space, quantum-information, quantum-computer

To construct a qubit, we need two quantum states, $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$. Why can't we use the ground and first excited states of a quantum harmonic oscillator such as a superconducting $LC$ circuit?

Comment: At low enough temperatures $\hbar \omega >> kT$ a superconducting circuit becomes a QHO. A SQUID is usually made of two Josephson junctions (dc-SQUID) which have nonlinear inductance and can be used as a Qubit if you put half of the flux quantum in the loop.

Comment: @Cryo an LC circuit is definitely well described as a quantum harmonic oscillator as long as $\hbar \omega \gg k_b T$, as Arsaces says in their comment. The SQUID is not needed to get a circuit that behaves as a quantum harmonic oscillator. The reason we use the SQUID in practice is for the nonlinearity, which allows the circuit to behave as a qubit.

Comment: Arsaces, let's start with a very simple question: how would you get the LC circuit to go from $\lvert 0 \rangle$ to $\lvert 1 \rangle$?

Comment: @DanielSank. Yep. I think you are correct. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key problem is a harmonic oscillator are the equally spaced energy levels $|0\rangle$, $|1\rangle$, $|2\rangle$, and so on.

The issue is the following: Imagine you want to flip the state of the qubit, i.e., get $|0\rangle$ to $|1\rangle$ and vice versa. So you would drive the transition between $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ (e.g. using some microwave which matches the transition frequency).  However, the *same* microwave would also drive the transition from $|1\rangle$ to $|2\rangle$ -- that is, if your qubit was in the $|1\rangle$ state (or analogously for any superposition), it would now be brought into a superposition of the $|0\rangle$ and the $|2\rangle$ state.  Once you are in the $|2\rangle$ state, you would also get in the $|3\rangle$ state, and so on ...  and there goes your nice qubit: Your system constantly leaks into states which are part of your qubit space.

That's the key reason why one needs non-linearities (such as the Josephson junction in a SQUID): To get a *non-linear* oscillator (i.e. and LC circuit with a non-linearity), which does no longer have equally spaced energy levels, and thus it is possble to address the $|0\rangle\leftrightarrow|1\rangle$ transition without exciting other states as well.

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I believe that someone once explained to me that it actually is quite possible to use a harmonic system as a single qubit, but that the problem comes in when trying to do a logic gate between two harmonic systems.

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense!

Comment: @DanielSank I'd love to see a source on that!  All I can imagine on the spot is an entirely different encoding, such as all |n> states with n even vs. n odd, respectively, but that this an entirely different "qubit" (basically a "noise-free subsystem").  So I think in essence the point is still the one I make above: If you want to encode your qubit in {|0>,|1>}, avoiding leakage requires unequal level spacing.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch yes, you can't make $\lvert n \rangle$ without some kind of nonlinearity. A purely linear drive makes coherence states. But I didn't want to inject the assumption that the energy states $\lvert n=0\rangle$ and $\lvert n=1 \rangle$ are the qubit logical states, because OP never said that.

Comment: @DanielSank The OP *literally* said that. -- *"To construct a qubit, we need two quantum states, |0⟩ and |1⟩. Why can't we use the ground and first excited states of a quantum harmonic oscillator [...] ?"*

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Haha, you're right! I guess I read that post with some pretty thickly biased mental lenses.